# How to update Theia version, used in the image?

Tags: eclipse-che, theia

When building `eclipse/che-theia` docker image https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/master/dockerfiles/theia, how to specify a specific version of Theia to be used ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of argument `THEIA_VERSION` in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/eclipse/che/blob/master/dockerfiles/theia/Dockerfile).

Beware of the CQ to be created for each Theia version upgrade.
Patches are per Theia version, so no need to remove them.
Integration tests are executed by default. Upgrading Theia may require updating integration tests.